# Maximum Descending Speed

Tags: road-bike, speed, downhill, road, physics

This is a hypothetical question but I'm curious.  Assuming an endless, freshly paved road with no turns, what would be my maximum speed?

**EDIT**
My question is too general so to help I'm adding some extra assumptions:

- 19 degree slope [like Baldwin St.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baldwin_Street)
- Tuck is hands on drops, back horizontal as described in [this study](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/which-cyclist-hill-descent-position-really-superior-froome-blocken)
- Still air conditions (no head/tail/crosswinds) winds
- No special suit, just normal warm weather road kit

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cycling_records

Comment: Even at a fast everyday downhill riding speed of +40mph the difference between hoods and drops is dramatic -- every little bit of drag counts.  So there is no tucked vs. not tucked; it's a continuum.  Steepness makes a big difference -- how steep a hill can your hypothetical bike descend?  This will very with the height of the centre of gravity -- more tucked will mean a steeper slope before your C of G is over the front axle as well as with the wheelbase.  Are you considering pedalling or not?

Comment: I once broke 60 on a downhill.  But I very quickly reined it in after I hit that mark, since going that fast is *scary*.  In such a situation sitting upright vs riding on the drops probably cuts top speed 15-20 mph.

Comment: +1 for Baldwin Street in Dunedin.  That is one damn scary road.

Comment: -1 for substantially changing a question with an answer.

Comment: the mass of the ridee and bike is also important

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus - The mass of the bike+rider is only relevant relative to the frontal area of the bike+rider.

Comment: @Daniel R Hicks Nope, more mass means more force due to gravity means higher terminal velocity against a retarding force like air resistance.

Comment: http://bikecalculator.com/  only goes to -20% grade, whereas Baldwin Street would be -38%  80kg rider on 10kg bike, clinchers, on drops, no wind, 25 degrees C, putting in 0 watts (ie coasting)  would do 120 km/h and do 10 km in 5 minutes.     Pedalling at 500W increases this by ~5 km/h total.    Baldwin street is 350 metres long, so you would complete it in 10 seconds, but would you get up to speed in 10 seconds?

Answer (score 3):

*The question has been changed since this answer was posted.*

On an 85° grade you would approach terminal velocity for a sky diver of about 120 mph.

It does not need to be endless. You approach terminal velocity pretty quickly.

Comment: I think we have to account for elevation. Assuming the track is endless we can assume you are starting off at 100,000 feet where the atmosphere is thinner which will increase your terminal velocity.

Comment: @Kibbee Gravity would be less also.  Not going down that road with you.

Comment: At 100,000 feet we still have about 99% of the gravity on sea level. Less atmospheric drag will be the dominating effect. Unless of corse we start much further outside, say near the moon.

Comment: Btw, a 90% grade would "only" be 42°. I don't think that's enough for the  terminal velocity of a sky diver.

Comment: Skydivers typically adopt a very un-aerodynamic position: I'd expect a tucked cyclist to have a rather higher terminal velocity. According to Wikipedia, diving head-down (as if diving into a pool from a diving board) will get you to over 300mph, and Felix Baumgartner got to over 800mph on his high-altitude record jump.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Original question was not tucked.   If you have an answer you are welcome to post it.

Comment: "No special suit, just normal warm weather road kit" - rules out any altitude above about 10000ft (cold will get you before lack of oxygen). Freshly paved road is also a serious problem above about 300000ft. (Some claim the route to teh top off everest is a paved road.....:) )

Answer (score 3):

Terminal velocity is reached when the force on the rider due to gravitation acceleration equals the force from aerodynamic drag on the rider and bicycle plus rolling resistance of the bicycle.

In the calculation below I will assume rolling resistance of the bicycle is much less than the air drag and will omit it. I may update this later. I will use typical values for gravity, air density etc at sea level on Planet Earth.

Gravitational force on the rider and bike *F* = *m* × *g* × sin(ϕ)

- *m* is mass of rider and bike 80kg for rider 10kg for bike is 90kg
- *g* is gravitational acceleration 9.81 m/s²
- ϕ is the slope *in radians*, 19° is 0.33 radians

That yields a force of approx. 287.4 Newtons

Aerodynamic drag force is *CdA* × ρ × *v*² / 2

- *CdA* is drag coefficient × frontal area, I'll use a figure of 0.275 from the page linked to by the OP.
- ρ is air density 1.225 kg/m²
- *v* is velocity.

Terminal velocity is therefore  √ ( 2 *F* / ( *CdA* × ρ ) ) which yields 41.3 m/s or about 149 km/h, 92.5 mph.

Comment: That seems high to me.

Comment: @Paparazzi, yeah I have to admit it seems high to me too. I'm looking for data to back it up or prove it's in the right ballpark.

Comment: @Paparazzi ... although the road referenced by the OP is crazy steep. Interestingly, if I plug 45° (the max slope of a double diamond ski run, according to Wikipedia) into my calculation, I get about 220km/h, which is comparable with the speeds in the table L.Dutch provided

Comment: Might be good.  I saw a racer stat of 85 mph on 10°.  But 160 mph for 90° still seems high but terminal velocity I quoted is based on spread out.

Comment: Plugging 10°. into the formula yields 108.6 km/h, 67.5 mph, but that's with no pedaling input, so 85mph for a racer on that slope seems plausible.

Comment: Wikipedia page on skydiving terminal velocity give a *CdA* of 0.5 for a spread out skydiver, if I plug that in with a slope of 90°- surprise: 193.3 km/h, 120.1 mph!

Comment: I agree.  I still don't like the OP changed a question that much rather than accept my answer but no big deal.

Answer (score 2):

Claudio Chiappucci reported that during the World Championship in Colombia in 1995 he had reached 90 kmh.

Then you can also visit [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_cycling_records), where you can find this table

[image]

Comment: 90 kph on a road bike is fairly slow. It is not uncommon to hit 100 kph+ on a descent in a race. I used to hit 85 kph almost daily on a commute.

Comment: @Rider_X you must ride like a madman

Answer (score 0):

I know nothing about the theory. But the world record for gravity bike is, according to Guinness, 103km/h. (http://www.guinnessworldrecords.com/world-records/71665-fastest-gravity-speed-bike)